# Fancybox 2 elastic 'orig' option not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have some fancybox images, but the anchor link is an image overlay element, instead of directly wrapping the image.

So, for the elastic animation to look like it's coming from the image, instead of from the center of the screen, I would have to use the option 'orig'.

Although I can't get it to work, and it even breaks the elastic animation.

Html:

```
<div class="content-art"'.$scrollspy.'>
    <img src="'.$item['thumb'].'" />
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn-art btn-fullscreen" rel="gallery" href="'.$item['image'].'">Fullscreen view</a><br />
            <a class="btn-art btn-moreinfo">more info</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.paintings-wrapper').find('.btn-fullscreen').fancybox(
{
    orig          : $(this).parents('.content-art').find('img'),
    padding       : 10,
    autoWidth     : true,
    arrows        : false,
    closeBtn      : false,
    scrollOutside : true,
    openSpeed     : 350,
    closeSpeed    : 250,
    openEffect    : 'elastic',
    closeEffect   : 'elastic',
    helpers       : {
        overlay   : {
            closeClick : true,
            locked     : true
        }
    }
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Aparently, as soon as I click my overlay element, to open the fancybox, the overlay hides — which makes sense, since it's only visible on hover — and causes fancybox to open from the center of the page.

Is there any work-around for this, perhaps?

Comment: `orig` is an option for v1.3.x and deprecated in v2.x. Elastic transitions are based on the clicked (or current) element http://jsfiddle.net/e6gqf3p7/

Comment: @JFK Thanks! I've found the cause of my problem, though. See my update.